# Nonholonomic version of bijection between $r$th order connection on $TM$ and principal connection on $r$th order frame bundle $P^r M$?

Tags: principal-bundles, jets

Given a smooth manifold $M$, [Kolář - On the torsion of linear higher order connections](https://doi.org/10.2478/bf02475215) showed that there is an equivalence between a linear, $r$-th order connection the tangent bundle $TM$ of $M$, and a principal connection on the $r$-th order frame bundle $P^r M$ over $M$.

I am interested in higher order frame bundles of the nonholonomic variety.  That is to say if we consider the higher order frame bundle $P^r M$ to be bundle of invertible $r$-jets over $M$ at the origin $\operatorname{Inv}(J^r M)$, then we would consider the nonholonomic frame bundle to be the bundle of invertible *nonholonomic* $r$-jets $\operatorname{Inv}(\smash{\tilde{J}}^r M)$ at the origin.  Where nonholonomic jets indicate the iterative application of the 1-jet prolongation, i.e. $$\smash{\tilde{J}}^r M = (J^1)^r M$$
Is anyone aware of any kind of analogous result to Kolář's for this case?
I would expect an analogue as $\smash{\tilde{J}}^r M$  is itself a principal bundle over $J^r M$ (see for example [de Léon and Martin Méndez - Principal bundle structures among second order frame bundles](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.difgeo.2016.04.002)).